# A question about normal space and uniform space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact and Hausdorff space. Hence there is a uniformity $\mathcal{U}$ on $X$, also  $X$ is normal space i.e. for every point $x\in X$ and every closed set $A\subseteq X$ there exist open sets $U, V$ such that $x\in U$, $A\subseteq V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Can I say that there is an entourage $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $U[x]\cap U[A]=\emptyset$, where $U[x]=\{y: (x, y)\in U\}$?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: The part of your first paragraph after "i.e." defines regularity, not normality.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an entourage $W$ such that $W[x]$ is disjoint from $A$. Since $\mathcal U$ is a uniformity, there is an entourage $U$ such that $U=U^{-1}$ and $U\circ U\subseteq W$. Then $U[x]\cap U[A]\varnothing$.

Comment: I have a question about uniform space. In my research $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is a uniform space and $A\subseteq X$ is a closed set while $x\notin A$. What condition imply that there is an entourage $U\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\overline{U[A]}\cap \overline{U[x]}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Is it true that if its topology of uniformity $\mathcal{U}$ is Urysohn space then for every closed set $A$ and $x\notin A$, there is an entourage $U\in\mathcal{U}$ with $\overline{U[A]}\cap \overline{U[x]}=\emptyset$?